# Access blob with one more security in azure android

Tags: android, azure, azure-blob-storage

i am storing my data to azure blobs. if the container name known, then we can access all the blobs in that container. but i need to make some authentication for accessing the blobs.

Example : set some password to access the blob while creating it.

send the password to get the blob's content.

is this possible?

code retrieve the blob without any authnetication:

```
       for (ListBlobItem blobItem : container.listBlobs()) {
            // If the item is a blob, not a virtual directory
            if (blobItem instanceof CloudBlockBlob) {
                // Download the text
                CloudBlockBlob retrievedBlob = (CloudBlockBlob) blobItem;
                act.outputText(view, retrievedBlob.downloadText());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Blob storage supports 3 access levels - Public which enables anonymous read and listing of all the blobs in a container, Blob read - where an anonymous request can read blobs but not list the contents of the container to find others or No public access.  These permissions are detailed here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-manage-access-to-resources

For your needs I think Shared Access Signatures (SAS) would be a good bet - the article below has an example which I think should help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-2

The SAS documentation is available here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1

Finally the article listed below has a good summary of the topic:
https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/platform-as-a-service/azure-blob-storage-part-9-shared-access-signatures/

HTH

Comment: Hi Ian. thank you very much for you suggestion. In SAS doc, i have seen creating blob with SAS generation. but i dont know how to retrieve the blob content which was created using SAS generation. Can you please suggest about this.

Comment: Hi Vji, no worries I just want to check how you need auth?  So for example in order to access the storage account to set the SAS etc. or indeed your originally snippet you are authenticating in the code via one of the two account keys so the app is authenticating.  You can set the access policy of the container to private if that suits your needs?  If you need to share access to another app or 3rd party SAS is your friend.  The second link provided includes a section on returning the URI used to access the Blob as a 3rd party.  Apologies if I have misunderstood your comment